# Solution Verification: Find the volume under the following surface.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

> Find the volume under the surface $z=x^2+y^2$ 
> above the domain :
> $A= \{(x,y,z) : 1\le x^2+y^2 \le 100, \frac{x}{\sqrt{3}} \le y \le x, z=0 \}$.

**My Work:** 
Let $x=r\cos(t)$ and $y=r\sin(t)$. the Jacobian absolute value is $r$. 
Now, $1\le x^2 + y^2\le100 \Longrightarrow 1\le r^2\le 100 \Longrightarrow$ I will take $r= \pm 1, \pm 10$ (just to be able to draw my domain). 
then, $\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}} \le y \le x, z=0 \Longrightarrow \frac{r\cos(t)}{\sqrt{3}} \le r\sin(t) \le r\cos(t)$, I can divide by $r$, because $r$ here represents distance, and it meants nothing when it's $0$ (Would love to hear feedback about this sentence). $\Longrightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \le \tan(t) \le 1 \Longrightarrow 
$$\frac{\pi}{6} \le t \le \frac{\pi}{4}$, Edit: $\frac{7\pi}{6} \le t \le \frac{5\pi}{4}$ 
Now I can see that my integral is over rectangular domain, and the surface is $z=r^2$. 
So $\int ^{\pi /4}_{\pi / 6}dt\int^{10}_{1}r^2 * r dr + \int ^{\pi /4}_{\pi / 6}dt\int^{-1}_{-10}r^2 * r dr = \frac{\pi}{12}* (\frac{r^4}{4} |^{10}_1 + \frac{r^4}{4}|^{-1}_{-10})=\frac{\pi}{12}(2499.75-2499.75)=0$
It feels so strange to get an answer of $0$, and I feel like I have made mistakes. 
Would really appreciate any help and feedback, thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** 
I just noticed that there's something fishy with $r$ being negative, since $r$ is distance, so I think I need to cut off the negative part of the integral.

**After Edit Solution:** 
$\int ^{\pi /4}_{\pi / 6}dt\int^{10}_{1}r^3dr = \frac{\pi}{12}(2499.75)=\frac{3333\pi}{16}$ 
**Edit 2: Added missing $t$ values** 
By symmetery we just multiply by $2$ and get $\frac{3333\pi}{8}$ as final answer.

Comment: Your edit pretty much takes care of the problem, good job!

Comment: You are right about $r$. Note that if you divide by a negative number $r$, the sign of inequality changes: $-10<-1$, when divided by $-1$ becomes $10>1$

Comment: Please keep $1 \leq r \leq 10$. For $t$, $7\pi/6 \leq t \leq 5\pi/4$

Comment: Or just use the symmetry to multiply your result from first quadrant by $2$.

Comment: First of all thanks to all of you for the help, @MathLover could you explain the domain of $t$? I was really confused if I should take the answers you gave or not, could you emphasize on how do I decide to take all the answers in the range $0 - 2\pi$, and when do I not?

Comment: In this case, there is no constraint that is restricting the domain to first quadrant. We are bound between two planes $y = x/\sqrt3$ and $y =x$. Now these planes pass through origin and are in first and third quadrant (either both $x$ and $y$ are positive or both are negative). In polar coordinates, if we go from $t = 0$ anti-clockwise $y = x / \sqrt3$ at $t = 7\pi/6$ or just use the fact that $\tan (\pi + t) = \tan t$

Comment: @MathLover You gave Pwaol incorrect advice. The domain *is* restricted to the first quadrant because in the third quadrant the inequalities are reversed i.e. $ x \leq y \leq \frac{x}{\sqrt{3}}$. Had it been $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \leq \frac{y}{x} \leq 1$, then it would have included both quadrants.

Comment: Your final answer should be $\frac{3333\pi}{16}$, not doubled.

Comment: @NinadMunshi oops! you are right. To Pwaol, NinadMunshi is correct. I overlooked. It is indeed only first quadrant.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thanks!! could you please emphasize on what inequality made you infer that? I feel like inferring the domain of the angle is my biggest weakness in these questions

Comment: In third quadrant $y \leq x$ would mean you are below $y = x$ plane and $y \geq x/\sqrt3$ would mean you are above that plane. So you do not have any volume bound in 3rd quadrant.

Comment: @Pwaol I hope it is clear. If not, let me know.

Comment: @MathLover To be honest I still don't quite get it, like I can understand it a little, but I don't think that if I see an inequality like it again I'll be able to infer that myself, I would appreciate if you have some similar examples

Comment: I will share a desmos link, that may help

Comment: I have $3$ points in 3rd quadrant and lines $y = x$ and $y = x/ \sqrt3$. Can you check if the point between the lines meets the condition $x/\sqrt3 \leq y \leq x$ https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bndj4hqgwo

Comment: @MathLover Thanks alot it's much more clear now. just the $y=x$ makes it possible that every point above it will get $y\ge x$ and every point under it will get $y\le x$

Comment: absolutely you got it. If you ever get confused, follow this simple step.